# CMSIS & STM32, How to begin?

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, cmsis

I'm want to start projects using CMSIS on STM32. Surfing the net, I couldn't find any specific tutorial. Some starts project using SPL (which is discontinued by ST). I want a source to learn CMSIS on stm32cube.

I'll glad if someone help me with that.

regards

Answer (score 7):

1. Download and install STM32Cube
2. Create new STM32 cube project for your micro (I have created for STM32F446RE Nucleo
   [image]
   [image]
   3.Name the project and press next and finish.
   [image]
3. Remove HAL drivers:
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
4. Open `main.c` Delete its content. Now you can start writing CMSIS bare metal code.
   [image]
5. Compile and start debugging (if you use dev board or have a debug probe)
   [image]
   [image]

Enjoy

Comment: One can also create an empty project and manually add CMSIS which can be downloaded from its official github page.

Comment: @Tagli the beginner and "manually" are not good partners :). I have shown the way which will set all paths and other stuff without user intervention - the easy way

Comment: @Tagli do you really think that someone asking this question will clone the fit repo, add it to the project and configure the settings?

Answer (score 1):

1. Buy a Discovery or Nucleo development board from STMicro.
2. Choose, download, and install a toolchain such as Keil, IAR, or STM32CubeIDE.
3. Download the STM32Cube library/example software package for your development.
   board from their website.  It includes CMSIS.
4. Get the blinky example running on your development board.
5. Then explore the other examples.