# RAM shortage when converting 8bit AVR project to STM32

Tags: stm32, avr, freertos

I currently have a working prototype running FreeRTOS and 128x128 dots graphical display.
With -O1 optimization it fitted inside a Atmega4809 with 6 KB RAM

```
> Program Memory Usage  :   46114 bytes   93,8 % Full 
> Data Memory Usage     :   4789 bytes   77,9 % Full
```

My new prototype has a 8KB STM32G030C8 but already FreeRTOS via HAL/CMSIS_V2 did't fit.
I turned off all features I did not use and had heap_1 selected like my previous project.

Only with CMSIS_V1 I managed to program a bare FreeRTOS project.

But adding the lcd display code, already compiled to the same issue.
I had fonttables with PROGMEM on the AVR project, using const puts them in flash on the STM32 project.

I also have one lcd framebuffer made:

```
uint8_t buffer[2048];
```

Does this compiles to 2048 32 bit values?

I'm not even close to moving all my AVR code to STM32 and already out of RAM, I'm really curious how this is possible.

UPDATE: This is FreeRTOS stripped out with only lcd code:
[image]

```
arm-none-eabi-size  STM32G030C8-48pin.elf 
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  33136     180    6804   40120    9cb8 STM32G030C8-48pin.elf
```

So my 2kB buffer is there, but 1,5kB .user_heap_stack?

Doesn't heap_1 of FreeRTOS aready manage heap stack?

Comment: uint8_t is supposed to be 8 bits (1 byte), so... idk

Comment: Get [my `size_mcu` program here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/598163/26234). Run it on the AVR .elf and the STM32 .elf file and paste the output into your question. Example usage: `size_mcu arm-none-eabi-size "STM32F103RB_Nucleo.elf" --flash 131072 --ram 20480`

Comment: Also run `objdump -h my.elf` on each of the .elf files, and paste that into your question. [Example usage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/363931/26234): `objdump -h STM32F103RB_Nucleo.elf`

Comment: Doing that will give us some insight into how the memory is being used in the two different systems.

Comment: Also, are you using Progmem or the Arduino `F()` macro in the AVR code? It explicitly moves variables, such as string text, from RAM to Flash on AVR, which can save a *ton* of RAM space. On STM32, making it `const` in C or `constexpr` in C++ can have the same effect, moving it to the `.rodata` (read-only data) section in STM32, which is in Flash only, not RAM, just like Progmem (see [here](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html) and [here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/)) on AVR.

Comment: My mistake: you already mention that: `But adding the lcd display code, already compiled to the same issue. I had fonttables with PROGMEM on the AVR project, using const puts them in flash on the STM32 project.`

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux? If on Windows, you'll need to run my command above inside a Git Bash terminal ([my instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76950661/4561887)), or MSYS2 terminal ([my instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77407282/4561887)).

Comment: What about WSL?

Comment: WSL works too, but doesn't run Windows executables. Git Bash and MSYS2 can build and run native Windows executables. WSL truly *is* Linux.

Comment: I'm on Windows. Is it smart to shrink the heap stack a bit inside the ld file?

Comment: @user3411864, I don't know. Probably not. Your program (main thread prior to starting FreeRTOS) needs at least a stack. I still haven't seen the 2 sets of `size_mcu` and `objdump` output, though, which I requested in my first two comments and think would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry not sure how to do the objdump on windows

Comment: Try perhaps `arm-none-eabi-objdump`.

Comment: But we need the comparison between your two chips.

Comment: If your AVR project had a smaller stack and/or heap, and you want to do the same in the ST project. If you're using a linker script from ST there are probably `_Min_Heap_Size` and `_Min_Stack_Size` variables in the .ld linker script that you can tweak manually.

Comment: 76 bytes for htim3?  You're using some very wasteful library (ST's HAL?)  that requires 76 bytes of RAM just to control a timer.  Same thing for the ADC, UART, and I2C.  Try using "LL" instead of "HAL", it's another library from ST that is less wasteful (but still not great).

Comment: During routing of the board I used cubeMX to have an overview of all the pins and get warnings if I have conflicting pin functionality. After that, generated the code. With Freertos enabled and HAL is used during code generation. Can cubeMX use LL? Or can I turn off code generation and only use cubeMX as a reference. Because on my Atmel project I directly write ports and registers without any fancy functions.

Comment: Of course you can use LL with cubeMX. In your cubeMX, click on "Project Manager" tab, click on "Advanced Settings" and click on every peripheral on "Driver Selector" to switch from HAL to LL before generating the code. You can even setup the environment for cmsis programming, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68193192/cmsis-stm32-how-to-begin).